# Android canvas draw complex shape defined by multiple simpler shapes

Tags: android, graphics, android-canvas, shapes

I want to draw something similar to this shape on android canvas:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/eQOHz.png]

I think the best way is to define this shape as the intersection of 2 circles and a line. What's the proper way to create this with android canvas?

***UPDATE***
I am now using PorterDuff as smith324 suggested:

*Note: code slightly simplified for clarity.

```
darkPaint = new Paint();
darkPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(50, 50, 50));

lightPaint = new Paint();
lightPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(200, 200, 200));

atopPaint= new Paint(GameDrawingPanel.darkPaint.getColor());
atopPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_ATOP));
atopPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
atopPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);

_boardCanvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, darkPaint);
_boardCanvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius_small, lightPaint);
_boardCanvas.drawRect(0,0,height,width,atopPaint);
```

Comment: Please use [tag:android-canvas] when talking about the native Java Android canvas and [tag:canvas] when talking about HTML5 canvas on Android devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forget exactly which modes would be of use here (XOR should work), but essentially you need to use a PorterDuff transfer mode to achieve this. Try drawing the concentric circles atop one another, then a dividing rectangle on one side.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html

http://www.svgopen.org/2005/papers/abstractsvgopen/

Comment: "[Sa + Da - Sa*Da, Sc*(1 - Da) + Dc*(1 - Sa) + min(Sc, Dc)]" What does all this mean?? :0

Comment: Ah, I understand it now. Thanks for this! Unfortunately I can't seem to get it to work. I drew some concentric circles with drawCircle, and tried to overlay a rectangle over it. No matter which mode I use, the rectangle either doesn't show up at all, or shows up everywhere (even outside of the circles).